# Javascript setInterval loop stopping

Tags: javascript

i want to clear the interverl when the h = 0; m = 0; s = 0;

how to do that... this is looping always...

look at the codes

```
var h = 10;
var m = 11;
var s = 12;


function countdown() {

    h--;
    m--;
    s--;

    var t = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = t;


    if (h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

}

var timer = setInterval('countdown()',1000);

countdown();
```

Comment: what errors return from your console on your browser?

Comment: It is bad practice to set the function to be executed in set interval as a `string`, I would recommend you to just write `setInterval(countdown,1000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your condition like this

```
if (h > 0)
h--;
if (m > 0)
m--;
if (k > 0)
s--;
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/UsQwp/)

Answer (score 2):

`h`, `m` and `s` reach 0 at different points so they never all equal zero at the same time.

You need to prevent them from decrementing lower than 0 by doing:

```
if (h) h--;
if (m) m--;
if (s) s--;
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Kn296/*

Answer (score 1):

`h`, `m`, `s` won't be `0` at the same time, so `h == 0 && m == 0 && s == 0` will never be `true`.

That's why your loop never stop.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your `h`, m and `s` values are never equal to zero at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

h, m ans s are not 0 at the same time.

so you have to check if they are equal or less then 0. Change your if-clause like that:

```
if(h <= 0 && m <= 0 && s <= 0){ 
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

**Update**

I missed, that you want to show the numbers on screen...
Then you should just decrese the variables, if they are bigger than 0

```
if(h>0) h--;
if(m>0) m--;
if(s>0) s--;
```

Comment: This will display minus values